# Filtering a log file by keyword and coloring the output

Tags: bash, shell, unix, text, sed

I wrote a bash script that uses sed to create a command that filters text by keywords and then colors the output. I did a lot of trial and error, and googling for techniques. I know this can be improved. Can anybody offer suggestions?

I'd like to be able to use this like tail too - filter and color tail output in real time. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

```
function multigrep(){

#THIS WORKS - Recreate this, using input parameters
#sed -En '/(App)|(Spe)/p' ./flashlog.txt;

filename="/Users/stevewarren/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/Logs/flashlog.txt";
paramString="";

for element in "$@"
    do
        #echo $element;
        paramString="$paramString($element)|";
    done

#TRIM FINAL | OFF PARAMSTRING
paramString=${paramString:0:${#paramString}-1};

#CREATE SED EXPRESSION - '/($1)|($2)|(...)/p'
paramString="'/$paramString/p'";

#CREATE SED FUNCTION, CALL ON FILE
paramString="sed -En $paramString ./flashlog.txt"

echo $paramString;
echo "${txtbld}$(tput setaf 7)" > ./flashlog_output.txt;
eval $paramString >> ./flashlog_output.txt;
echo >> ./flashlog_output.txt;
#cat ./flashlog_output.txt;

cat ./flashlog_output.txt | while read LINE
do

    [[  $1 && ${1-x} ]] && 
        if grep -q $1 <<<$LINE; then
            echo "$(tput setaf 3)$LINE"
        fi

    [[  $2 && ${2-x} ]] && 
        if grep -q $2 <<<$LINE; then
            echo "$(tput setaf 7)$LINE"
        fi


    [[  $3 && ${3-x} ]] && 
        if grep -q $3 <<<$LINE; then
            echo "$(tput setaf 6)$LINE"
        fi

done
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know about [colortail](http://www.console-colors.de/index.php?n=ColorizerTools.ColorTail)? I'm using it too. You can configure the colorization using regexes in the config file. The output will look like: (yeah! :)

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. I would advice you to compile it from sources. Linux distributions may have older version's that have a memory leak that is sometimes annoying. But however, problem is not often.